# Getting all hierarchical parents until root of a leaf node in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I am storing folder tree structure in NoSQL in the below format.

```
Document{{_id=587bedc1da0847d7ad8b7056, name=firstlevel, parent_folder=null}}
Document{{_id=587beddcda0847d7ad8b7057, name=secondlevel, parent_folder=firstlevel}}
Document{{_id=587bedf2da0847d7ad8b7058, name=thirdlevel, parent_folder=secondlevel}}
```

I need to get the parents of `thirdlevel` where my output should consist of both `firstlevel`, `secondlevel`, `thirdlevel`(optional as i already know which level i am in). Could anyone suggest me what kind of model tree structure do i need to follow or can it be done without the model tree structure like parent, child, ancestors, path etc.,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current Mongo 3.4 version you can make use of `$graphLookup`.

If you have something like below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("587bedc1da0847d7ad8b7056"),
    "name": "firstlevel",
    "parent_folder": null
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("587beddcda0847d7ad8b7057"),
    "name": "secondlevel",
    "parent_folder": "firstlevel"
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("587bedf2da0847d7ad8b7058"),
    "name": "thirdlevel",
    "parent_folder": "secondlevel"
}
```

Query for all parents.

```
db.nodes.aggregate([{
    $graphLookup: {
        from: "nodes",
        startWith: "$name",
        connectFromField: "parent_folder",
        connectToField: "name",
        as: "parents",
    }
}]);
```

Add a match stage for querying parents for `thirdlevel`

```
{$match:{name:"thirdlevel"}}
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    "name": "thirdlevel",
    "parents": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("587beddcda0847d7ad8b7057"),
        "name": "secondlevel",
        "parent_folder": "firstlevel"
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("587bedc1da0847d7ad8b7056"),
        "name": "firstlevel",
        "parent_folder": null
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("587bedf2da0847d7ad8b7058"),
        "name": "thirdlevel",
        "parent_folder": "secondlevel"
    }]
}
```